# catch_unwind signal SIGABRT when unwrap a Result inside it

Tags: rust

I develop an Android app that call some Rust (stable 1.37.0) native functions via JNI. And I want to catch any panic inside them to convert it into `java.lang.Error`.

So, I've read about `std::panic::catch_unwind` and decided to try it. But I received `signal Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL)` when tried to unwrap some custom Error.

```rust
///Some custom error
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyError;

impl Error for MyError {}

impl Display for MyError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        writeln!(f, "I'm an Error struct")
    }
}
```

1. **OK**. Catch the error above in Rust's unit tests or executable.

```rust
fn main() {
    let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        Result::<String, _>::Err(MyError).unwrap();
    });

    // works!
    if let (Err(_)) = result {
        println!("I'm an Error!")
    }
}
```

2. **SIGABRT**. Call it via jni on Android

```rust
/// Some function called from an Android thread
/// args omitted
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn Java_com_example_test() {
    // that won't help
    panic::set_hook(Box::new(|_| {}));

    let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        // signal Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL)
        Result::<String, _>::Err(MyError).unwrap();

        // BUT! These code will not abort the process and work properly
        //inner::unwrap(Result::<String, _>::Err(MyError));
        //Result::<(), _>::Err("error".to_string()).unwrap();

        ()
    });

    // doesn't work!
    if let (Err(_)) = result {
        println!("I'm an Error!")
    }
}

mod inner {
    #[inline]
    pub fn unwrap<T, E: ::std::fmt::Debug>(r: Result<T, E>) -> T {
        match r {
            Ok(t) => t,
            Err(e) => unwrap_failed("called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value", e),
        }
    }

    #[inline(never)]
    #[cold]
    fn unwrap_failed<E: ::std::fmt::Debug>(msg: &str, error: E) -> ! {
        panic!("{}: {:?}", msg, error)
    }
}
```

3. **OK**. Use futures catch_unwind on Android.

```rust
/// Some function called from an Android thread
/// args omitted
#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn Java_com_example_test2() {
    let result = futures::lazy(|| {
        if true {
            Err(MyError)
        } else {
            Ok("error".to_string())
        }
        .unwrap();

        futures::future::ok::<_, ()>(())
    })
    .catch_unwind()
    .wait();

    // works!
    if let (Err(_)) = result {
        println!("I'm an Error!")
    }
}
```

Same, but on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d23fcabfbbf973b69dda407083607b84).

I don't understand what is a difference between these variants? They are all use the panic! macro that work properly inside `panic::catch_unwind`.

Comment: You're assuming that the panic definition (done in your `target` and in your `Cargo.toml`) is set to `panic = unwind`. Check this; the default for not-cross-compiled rust code is `panic = unwind`, but the default for cross-compilation is `panic = abort`, which does **not** trigger unwind.

Comment: About `Cargo.toml`. That was my first thought. I set `panic = "unwind"` inside `[profile.release]` (I don't use debug builds for now). How to check it in my `target`? The strange thing is that if I change `Result<String, MyError>` to `Result<(), String>` all work fine and `catch_unwind` return proper Err. Or `futures` crate which can catch panic inside it if I use `Future.catch_unwind()`.